# Problem with building applications for 10.4

Tags: xcode, gcc, macos, sdk

When I try to build my app for 10.4, ppc, I get the following error:

`GCC 4.2 is not compatible with the Mac OS X 10.4 SDK (file MBM.m)`

What does this mean, and how can I stop it and build for 10.4?

MBM.m: http://localhostr.com/files/bb385f/MBM.m

Sorry for the brief explanation, but I have to go.

Please help,

HiGuy S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your compiler. Edit the active target (Project -> Edit Active Target) and find the **C/C++ Compiler Version** setting to change it to an older version of GCC. I think version 3 is appropriate; if you don't have it, and if I recall correctly, it's an optional install with the Developer Tools you should have on your Mac OS X CD.

Comment: You just need to switch to gcc 4.0 for OS X 10.4 deliverables.

Comment: Thanks! My apps are running fine now! (But I probably won't use 10.4 because of my NSFileManager techniques.)